# SNMP agent in Go

Tags: go, snmp

I need to write a SNMP agent and I would like to implement it in Go in order to keep it with a small footprint.

However, I haven't found any Go library that supports SNMP agents. Is there any library or alternative available, such as calling a library in C?

Answer (score 3):

As https://github.com/posteo/go-agentx is not under active development and has some bugs, I forked it into a new project to fix the bugs and accept contributions: https://github.com/martinclaro/go-agentx

Feel free to use it, report bugs, and contribute for a better solution.

Comment: Why it use dial instead of listen as SNMP Agent?

Answer (score 0):

I got the following Googling "golang snmp agent".

https://github.com/posteo/go-agentx

and

https://github.com/k-sone/snmpgo

Even if these aren't what you are looking for, they should be a good start in the right direction.